# How to get nodes credentials using jenkinsapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, pip, jenkins-api

I need to get credentials information (which credentials used) for node.
[image]

Currently I use this code that prints LOT of information but no credentials info that used for the node:

```
for node in get_server_instance().nodes._data['computer']:
    for i in node:
        print (i, node[i])
```

Is there any way to reach credentials ?

Thanks

Comment: What type of credentials are you using? What type of environment is Jenkins running in?

Comment: @vault I use crumb request for authorization

Comment: Does this address the issue? https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219257077-CSRF-Protection-Explained#resolution

Comment: @vault nope
Its just the data not exist in reply struct

Comment: I have set up Jenkins so each node is a docker container. With this environment, I just exec into the container and generate ssh keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is run grep "credentials" */config.xml on the server inside nodes directory